# Как задать landscape ориентацию?

Tags: android

как (желательно в манифесте) задать `landscape` ориентацию, но так чтобы при повороте устройства на 180 градусов, приложение тоже переворачивалось, а не стояло вверх ногами?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В манифесте вместо **landscape** указать **sensorLandscape**.

```
android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
```

При повороте устройства на 180 градусов, экран будет тоже перевернут.

Comment: @pavlofff согласно офф. документации https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html sensorLandscape был добавлен в API 9. Скорее всего вы перепутали с userLandscape, который был добавлен в API 18